# How do I fix italics in PDFs that display as bold italic under Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, fonts

Italics in a PDF created with Acrobat under MS Word display incorrectly for me as bold italic under Chrome but correctly under Edge, IE, Firefox and Safari.  This happens on both my desktop and my laptop machine, both running 64-bit Windows 10 Pro.  Here's [an example](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~nham/NicoleHamiltonCV2018.pdf) where the individual headings under "Experience" should be plain italic but aren't.

Can someone advise why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that might help:

- Change fonts. For a résumé, try [fonts that are likely to be installed with most operating systems](http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html), such as Arial, Times or Courier New. [Though I might prefer Garamond for a printed document, I'd use a more common font for one submitted online.]
- Embed fonts in the PDF. [Not all fonts can be embedded](http://www.copresco.com/lite05/0305ltx.htm), and embedding one increases the document's size.

Comment: Embedding the italic font worked.